# Who is the Nasi in Ezekiel?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, malchut-royalty, ezekiel--the-book

BS"D

I was rereading  Yehhezqei'l and was curious about the context of something towards the end.
In pereq 46 from 1-18 it talks about a Nasi (prince), for example :

**"And the prince, when they go in, shall go in in the midst of them; and when they go forth, they shall go forth together."** [v10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1246.htm#10)

Now is this chapter referring to the Nasi who is the head of the Sanhedrin or is it a ben hamelekh? or maybe even someone else im not familiar with?

Answer (score 3):

[Rashi to Yechezkeil 45:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14256&st=&pgnum=404) says that he thinks the Nasi in the end of that Sefer is the Kohein Gadol, but that he heard that Rav Menachem (?) thought it was the King. Metzudot and Malbim to [44:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14256&st=&pgnum=389) seem to agree with the latter view, although they don't explicitly extend it to all references to a Nasi.

Answer (score 2):

Both [Abravanel to Yehezkel 44:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14369&st=&pgnum=601&hilite=) (see also [46:18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14369&st=&pgnum=610&hilite=)) & the [Radak to 44:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14256&st=&pgnum=389)  states that the Nasi is Melech HaMoshiach.